# How do I make a synchronous call in a recursive method?

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, async-await, synchronous

I am trying to run a call and stop a recursive function from continuing to run before finishing another function.

I've tried to use a promise but I just don't understand what to what to put in the `.then()` portion as its a recursive call.

```
    const htmlString = '<table><tr><td>Bah</td><td>Pooh</td></tr></table>';
    const fragment = 
    document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlString);

    function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
        func(node);
        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walkTheDOM(node, func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    function asynchronousCallWantingtoMakeSynchronous() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           setTimeout(function() {
       return resolve ( console.log("should come before another recursive call"))
           }, 0)
       });
    }

    walkTheDOM(fragment, function(node) {
        console.log(node)
        asynchronousCallWantingtoMakeSynchronous.then(function(){

        })
    })
```

what this actually prints out:

```
    <table>...</table>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <td>Bah</td>
    "Bah"
    <td>Pooh</td>
    "Pooh"
    "should come before Pooh"
```

What I really want is:

```
    <table>...</table>
    "should come before another recursive call"
    <tr>...</tr>
    "should come before another recursive call"
    <td>Bah</td>
    "should come before another recursive call"
    "Bah"
    "should come before another recursive call"
    <td>Pooh</td>
    "should come before another recursive call"
    "Pooh"
    "should come before another recursive call"
```

Keep in mind, the setTimeout is just an example, I just want to make the asynchronous call synchronous.

Comment: `setTimeout` yields an **asynchronous** function, not a **synchronous** one.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated to be more clear. I want to make that asynchronous call synchronous.

Comment: Well, you're never going to make an asynchronous function synchronous.  But you might still be able to interleave the calls.

Comment: its not clear from the question, are you trying to get the required output using  `asynchronousCallWantingtoMakeSynchronous` as an asynchronous function or are you trying to convert `asynchronousCallWantingtoMakeSynchronous` to a synchronous function?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. I am trying to make `asynchronousCallWantingtoMakeSynchronous` to a synchronus function.

Comment: Then don't use `setTimeout`, which is inherently asynchronous.

Comment: I have updated the code to show what I have tried with a promise, except it throws an error.

Comment: @Scott as I explain in my question, setTimeout is just a way to demonstrate an API call, which is asynchronous, which I want to make synchronous.

Comment: But there is no way to make an asynchronous call synchronous.  The world doesn't work that way.

Comment: Thanks @Scott. You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make an asynchronous function synchronous.  But you can make it feel a bit more like that with `Promises` or `async-await`.  And you can use these to intersperse your calls

```js
const htmlString = '<table><tr><td>Bah</td><td>Pooh</td></tr></table>';
const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlString);

async function asyncWalkTheDOM(node, func, intersperse) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        await intersperse(node)
        asyncWalkTheDOM(node, func, intersperse);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}

async function asynchronousCall(node) {
  return new Promise(function (res, rej) { 
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("should come before another recursive call")
      res(node)
    }, 0)
  })
}

asyncWalkTheDOM(fragment, function(node) {
    console.log(node.nodeName)
}, asynchronousCall)
```